# Angular 9 Universal and SEO

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to go through SEO and make my website render it's data that crawlers can catch it

The server render and didn't wait my Ajax calls
So it renders [empty HTML tags](https://ibb.co/Cn7qdMj) .

I found that there is a solution regarding to Zones
Can anyone help ?

Comment: you need to add some relevant snippets of code in order for us to be able to help you. anyway, make sure you are updating the tags after you're fetching the data from the server. if you are using observables as you should, you can do it in the subscription or `tap` rxjs operator for side effects.

Comment: what did you mean with this "updating the tags after you're fetching the data from the server"

Comment: the client side rendering is working well the problem is with the server side rendering 
CSR : https://ibb.co/gVHjQCj

Comment: you should post the relevant code, including the ajax calls that you make and maybe the server file. and very important, the angular version.

Comment: The documentation does not do a great job of explaining how this is supposed to be done as with other SSR frameworks like next and nuxt, it's made much, much more clear how to accomplish this. If you review issues like [this](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1152), you will see that requests like this need to be done in the navigation route resolvers. This will not work in ngOnInit (as far as I know). This is technically done in conjunction with https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md

Comment: Maybe Scully.io is a better solution? It’s a lot easier than Universal for sure..

Comment: i will try this @MikeOne, thank you

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i'm trying to use what you're mention for but didnt get a solution

Comment: Can you show how you add the meta? And your index.html. adding meta in ngOnInit definitely works with angular universal, even without TransferState. Check for any errors in the console server side too

Comment: my problem is not with the meta it is with the data displaying